# In Firebase HTTP cloud functions, how can i return an object back to the client app within a stripe charge function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase http cloud function

```
exports.createCharge = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>{
```

Within this function, I am creating a Stripe charge

```
return stripe.charges.create(chargeInfo, { idempotency_key }, function (err, charge){

        if(err){
            return err.message;
        }else{
            return "done";
        }

    });
```

The stripe charge is the last line of code in the http function. My problem is the error message doesn't get returned back to the client, and the `task.getResult()` in my app comes back as null after completion. Also, variables do not persist outside of the stripe charge. `err` and `charge` must be used within the scope of the stripe charge function almost as if the stripe charge function is running in it's own environment. How can I return the `err` or `charge` back to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stripe.charges.create` is an `asynchronous` call and in order to return results/errors from an asynchronous call, `Firebase` function requires you return a Promise who will return the value [0]

So, in order to `err` or `charge`, instead of using `callback` like what code sample you've posted, `promise.then` should be used.

```
return stripe.charges.create(chargeInfo, { idempotency_key })
  .then((charge) => charge)
  .catch((error) => error);
```

Hope the above helps to address your issue.

[0] https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Oh i was trying to use it as a synchronous function  thank you.